# Dynamically add Select country and states by click on add more

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

my code is not refreshing the state list by clicking on add more and showing previous list.

For example is you select country afghanistan your are shown a list of states. But when you click add more and then select different country you are shown the same list of states.

```js
var country_arr = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antartica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia" );

// States
var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0]="";
s_a[1]="Badakhshan|Badghis|Baghlan|Balkh|Bamian|Farah|Faryab|Ghazni|Ghowr|Helmand|Herat|Jowzjan|Kabol|Kandahar|Kapisa|Konar|Kondoz|Laghman|Lowgar|Nangarhar|Nimruz|Oruzgan|Paktia|Paktika|Parvan|Samangan|Sar-e Pol|Takhar|Vardak|Zabol";
s_a[2]="Berat|Bulqize|Delvine|Devoll (Bilisht)|Diber (Peshkopi)|Durres|Elbasan|Fier|Gjirokaster|Gramsh|Has (Krume)|Kavaje|Kolonje (Erseke)|Korce|Kruje|Kucove|Kukes|Kurbin|Lezhe|Librazhd|Lushnje|Malesi e Madhe (Koplik)|Mallakaster (Ballsh)|Mat (Burrel)|Mirdite (Rreshen)|Peqin|Permet|Pogradec|Puke|Sarande|Shkoder|Skrapar (Corovode)|Tepelene|Tirane (Tirana)|Tirane (Tirana)|Tropoje (Bajram Curri)|Vlore";
s_a[3]="Adrar|Ain Defla|Ain Temouchent|Alger|Annaba|Batna|Bechar|Bejaia|Biskra|Blida|Bordj Bou Arreridj|Bouira|Boumerdes|Chlef|Constantine|Djelfa|El Bayadh|El Oued|El Tarf|Ghardaia|Guelma|Illizi|Jijel|Khenchela|Laghouat|M'Sila|Mascara|Medea|Mila|Mostaganem|Naama|Oran|Ouargla|Oum el Bouaghi|Relizane|Saida|Setif|Sidi Bel Abbes|Skikda|Souk Ahras|Tamanghasset|Tebessa|Tiaret|Tindouf|Tipaza|Tissemsilt|Tizi Ouzou|Tlemcen";
s_a[4]="Eastern|Manu'a|Rose Island|Swains Island|Western";
s_a[5]="Andorra la Vella|Bengo|Benguela|Bie|Cabinda|Canillo|Cuando Cubango|Cuanza Norte|Cuanza Sul|Cunene|Encamp|Escaldes-Engordany|Huambo|Huila|La Massana|Luanda|Lunda Norte|Lunda Sul|Malanje|Moxico|Namibe|Ordino|Sant Julia de Loria|Uige|Zaire";
s_a[6]="Anguilla";
s_a[7]="Antartica";
s_a[8]="Barbuda|Redonda|Saint George|Saint John|Saint Mary|Saint Paul|Saint Peter|Saint Philip";
s_a[9]="Antartica e Islas del Atlantico Sur|Buenos Aires|Buenos Aires Capital Federal|Catamarca|Chaco|Chubut|Cordoba|Corrientes|Entre Rios|Formosa|Jujuy|La Pampa|La Rioja|Mendoza|Misiones|Neuquen|Rio Negro|Salta|San Juan|San Luis|Santa Cruz|Santa Fe|Santiago del Estero|Tierra del Fuego|Tucuman";
s_a[10]="Aragatsotn|Ararat|Armavir|Geghark'unik'|Kotayk'|Lorri|Shirak|Syunik'|Tavush|Vayots' Dzor|Yerevan";
// <!-- -->



function populateStates( countryElementId, stateElementId ){
 
 var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById( countryElementId ).selectedIndex;

 var stateElement = document.getElementById( stateElementId );
 
 stateElement.length=0; // Fixed by Julian Woods
 stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State','');
 stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;
 
 var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");
 
 for (var i=0; i<state_arr.length; i++) {
  stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i],state_arr[i]);
 }
}

function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId){
 // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
 var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
 countryElement.length=0;
 countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country','-1');
 countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;
 for (var i=0; i<country_arr.length; i++) {
  countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i],country_arr[i]);
 }

 // Assigned all countries. Now assign event listener for the states.

 if( stateElementId ){
  countryElement.onchange = function(){
   populateStates( countryElementId, stateElementId );
  };
 }
}


  $('.addmore').click(function(e) {
      $clone = $('#country').clone();
      $clone.attr('id', 'country' + ($('.country').length + 1));
      $clone.insertBefore($('.button-div'));
    
        $clones = $('#state').clone();
        $clones.attr('id', 'state' + ($('.state').length + 1));
        $clones.insertBefore($('.button-div'));
    
    });


  populateCountries("country", "state");
```

```html
<div class="row" id="addparts">
  <div class="form-group" id="raghav">
    Select Country:
    <select id="country" name="country" class="country"></select></br></br>
    Select State:
    <select name="state" id="state" class="state"></select></br>
   
  </div>
</div>

<div class="button-div">
  <input type="button" name="addmore" class="addmore" value="Add More">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<body>
    <p>
        my code is not refreshing the state list by clicking on add more and showing previous list 
    </p>
    <div class="row" id="add_parts">
        <div class="form-group" id="">
            <select id="country" name ="country" class="country"></select>
            <select name ="state" id ="state" class="state"></select>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-div">
        <input type="button" name="add_more" class="add_more" value="Add More">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: what do you wanna make here ? please add countries.js content to your question and your code snippet not working

Comment: i have attached my countries.js , aloso my code snippet is working . Please take a look into my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna more than one field depend dynamic between Country and State you must define ID with dynamic numbers.

If you wanna you can set display limit for input boxes

```
var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
```

Code below is working you can try it

```js
   var country_arr = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antartica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia");

// States
var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0] = "";
s_a[1] = "Badakhshan|Badghis|Baghlan|Balkh|Bamian|Farah|Faryab|Ghazni|Ghowr|Helmand|Herat|Jowzjan|Kabol|Kandahar|Kapisa|Konar|Kondoz|Laghman|Lowgar|Nangarhar|Nimruz|Oruzgan|Paktia|Paktika|Parvan|Samangan|Sar-e Pol|Takhar|Vardak|Zabol";
s_a[2] = "Berat|Bulqize|Delvine|Devoll (Bilisht)|Diber (Peshkopi)|Durres|Elbasan|Fier|Gjirokaster|Gramsh|Has (Krume)|Kavaje|Kolonje (Erseke)|Korce|Kruje|Kucove|Kukes|Kurbin|Lezhe|Librazhd|Lushnje|Malesi e Madhe (Koplik)|Mallakaster (Ballsh)|Mat (Burrel)|Mirdite (Rreshen)|Peqin|Permet|Pogradec|Puke|Sarande|Shkoder|Skrapar (Corovode)|Tepelene|Tirane (Tirana)|Tirane (Tirana)|Tropoje (Bajram Curri)|Vlore";
s_a[3] = "Adrar|Ain Defla|Ain Temouchent|Alger|Annaba|Batna|Bechar|Bejaia|Biskra|Blida|Bordj Bou Arreridj|Bouira|Boumerdes|Chlef|Constantine|Djelfa|El Bayadh|El Oued|El Tarf|Ghardaia|Guelma|Illizi|Jijel|Khenchela|Laghouat|M'Sila|Mascara|Medea|Mila|Mostaganem|Naama|Oran|Ouargla|Oum el Bouaghi|Relizane|Saida|Setif|Sidi Bel Abbes|Skikda|Souk Ahras|Tamanghasset|Tebessa|Tiaret|Tindouf|Tipaza|Tissemsilt|Tizi Ouzou|Tlemcen";
s_a[4] = "Eastern|Manu'a|Rose Island|Swains Island|Western";
s_a[5] = "Andorra la Vella|Bengo|Benguela|Bie|Cabinda|Canillo|Cuando Cubango|Cuanza Norte|Cuanza Sul|Cunene|Encamp|Escaldes-Engordany|Huambo|Huila|La Massana|Luanda|Lunda Norte|Lunda Sul|Malanje|Moxico|Namibe|Ordino|Sant Julia de Loria|Uige|Zaire";
s_a[6] = "Anguilla";
s_a[7] = "Antartica";
s_a[8] = "Barbuda|Redonda|Saint George|Saint John|Saint Mary|Saint Paul|Saint Peter|Saint Philip";
s_a[9] = "Antartica e Islas del Atlantico Sur|Buenos Aires|Buenos Aires Capital Federal|Catamarca|Chaco|Chubut|Cordoba|Corrientes|Entre Rios|Formosa|Jujuy|La Pampa|La Rioja|Mendoza|Misiones|Neuquen|Rio Negro|Salta|San Juan|San Luis|Santa Cruz|Santa Fe|Santiago del Estero|Tierra del Fuego|Tucuman";
s_a[10] = "Aragatsotn|Ararat|Armavir|Geghark'unik'|Kotayk'|Lorri|Shirak|Syunik'|Tavush|Vayots' Dzor|Yerevan";



function populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId) {

    var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById(countryElementId).selectedIndex;

    var stateElement = document.getElementById(stateElementId);

    stateElement.length = 0; // Fixed by Julian Woods
    stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State', '');
    stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

    var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

    for (var i = 0; i < state_arr.length; i++) {
        stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i], state_arr[i]);
    }
}

function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId) {
// given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
    var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
    countryElement.length = 0;
    countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country', '-1');
    countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
        countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i], country_arr[i]);
    }

    // Assigned all countries. Now assign event listener for the states.

    if (stateElementId) {
        countryElement.onchange = function () {
            populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId);
        };
    }
}

$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper = $("#raghav"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button = $(".addmore"); //Add button ID

        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('Select Country: <select id="country'+x+'" name="country" class="country"></select> | Select State: <select id="state'+x+'" name="state" class="state"></select></br>');
                populateCountries("country"+x+"", "state"+x+"");
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
        })
    });

});
populateCountries("country", "state");
```

```html
<div class="row" id="addparts">
    <div class="form-group" id="raghav">
        Select Country: <select id="country" name="country" class="country"></select> | Select State: <select name="state" id="state" class="state"></select></br>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="button-div">
    <input type="button" name="addmore" class="addmore" value="Add More">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Its working now. Thanks for help i was scratching my head over this for the past one week. Thanks

Comment: @IvanBarayev: How to get the id of states, for ex: we are just giving values like this "Badakhshan|Badghis|Baghlan|Balkh|Bamian|Farah|Faryab|Ghazni". So may I know how to get the id of selected state as the value of option.

Comment: @IvanBarayev please review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557265/prevent-changing-of-later-drop-down-pair-which-added-by-add-more-button-when-f?noredirect=1&lq=1